# VScode Code Runner extension doing loop without asking

Tags: javascript, node.js, vscode-extensions, vscode-code-runner

so, i'm a rookie and i have a simple js file to print several string without any loop.
i run it by vscode Code Runner extension.
and the output just looping my program over and over until nodejs turn it off.

here is my code and errormessage, thx
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iVtq.png)
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQjBN.png)

i've test another simple file by Code Runner and it just go well

i'm wondering is there some setting i do wrong
or just Code Runner extension is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `fun()` from inside `fun()`. This is recursion, and causing an infinite loop.

For next time, please post code and errors as text surrounded in three backticks (```), not images.

Here is the correct code:

```
function fun(z) {
  console.log(`we have a argument named z`)
  console.log(`print by call the argumentName: ${z}`)
  console.log(`print by call the argument.length: ${arguments.length}`)
  console.log(`print by call the this.length: ${this.length}`)
  console.log(`print by call the functionName.length: ${fun.length}`)

  // This line is calling `fun()` from inside `fun()`, causing an infinite loop.
  // console.log(`print by call the functionName().length: ${fun().length}`)
}
let a = 5
fun(a);
```